# How to distribute a Web API 2 web app to my clients?

Tags: .net, iis, asp.net-web-api

I would like to distribute a Web API 2 app to my clients, but I want to only give them the output .dll-s and explain to them how to host them in a container as IIS. What is the general way to host the provided .dll-s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general way is to host Web API application on IIS. Here is a brief tutorial: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2b481f/how-to-host-Asp-Net-web-api-on-iis-server.

An alternative way is to host the Web API application outside IIS in an external app like console/desktop app/windows service and send them the app. Here is a tutorial how to do that: https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api.

Comment: Thanks! That was what I was looking for